# Create an annotation that forces a class where the annotation is applied to extend a particular superclass

Tags: java, annotations

Let's assume I have the following interface annotation `@MyAnnotation`.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@interface MyAnnotation {
}
```

I want to implement in such a way that when someone consumes the annotation at compile time they will be told that they must **extend** a certain base class for example

```
@MyAnnotation
class Concrete extends Base {

}
```

The `Base` class is an abstract class that contains helper methods etc. So the idea is if anyone wishes to use the annotation `MyAnnotation` they would get a helpful hint to say that they must extend class `Base`. Is this possible at all?

I believe the type checker framework (https://checkerframework.org/manual/) accomplishes similar aspirations to what I'm after in that it has a `SubtypeOf` annotation but that seems to accept classes that extend `java.lang.annotation.Annotation`. Thanks in advance as to any help with the above.

Comment: do you use any framework that supports annotation processing or AOP?

Comment: For now I'm not using annotation processing or AOP. I thought this could be possible to do by providing a class that extends class `javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor`?

Comment: as you want to use `javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor`, this link may help you: https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder. The strategy that I would pick to identify if a Class is extended or not is reflection. You get the Class and then get the information from it.